# Read/Write from a hdd inside a network device driver (Linux)

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am new in Linux programming. I want to customize an existing driver for my needs. It is the RealTek 8169 network driver.

My question is: I can access to a HDD inside the driver? Is this "allowed"? Or could I get some problems with this?

I want to do something like this:

```
  // Which disk?
  char diskName[] = "/dev/sda";
  std::string diskError = std::string() + diskName + ": ";

  // Open device file
  std::ifstream disk(diskName, std::ios_base::binary);

  if(!disk)
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));

  // Seek to 12345'th sector
  disk.seekg(512 * 12345);
  if(!disk)
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));

  // Read in one sector
  std::vector<char> buffer(512);
  disk.read(&buffer[0], 512);
  if(!disk)
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));
```

Comment: A well-written Linux device driver should not (a) rely on another device for configuration data (what happens if the device is "unavailable"?); (b) perform low-level operations on a device such as a seek; or (c) use a physical address on a storage device (there's a filesystem to abstract the physical layer).  Device configuration info is typically passed through the *kernel command line* at boottime, OR through the *init* process (and `/etc/init.d` files) after the kernel has booted.  Some processor architectures have additional mechanisms (e.g ARM and ATAG list).